# Should I use Image or WebBrowser for displaying image?

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, browser

I am standing between major decision in my WP7 application. It's majore purpose is to display images, always one at a time on fullscreen.

I need perfect support for pinch to zoom, moving image (while zoomed) and switching between images via flick gesture. Most of these things are already implemented in WebBrowser control, so I would just have to generate proper html source with path to image in Isolated storage.

Or should I use common Image control and implement these gestures on my own? I would like your advice before I make this decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you targeting Windows Phone 8 or 7?

Generally, I would implement my own.

Issues with using the web-browser:
1. Perf is going to be slower.

1. Memory footprint is going to be higher (though I doubt you really care about this - it's not going to be massive).
2. If you are going to favorite/download images, it will be harder (if at all possible) to navigate to them in the browser.
3. The background will always be white, unless you generate HTML each time that will control that bit.
4. The biggest issue is that the zooming in/out will be.. Janky... You won't be able to control how zoomed out the user can make it - meaning that they can zoom out enough to  make the picture very small and it won't "snap back".

It's not a bad stop-gap, and the issues with it are not so big that one can say "no - don't do it",  but they are enough that you should reconsider.

Comment: Thank you helped me a lot...again. I guess I will use the Image control then.

Comment: And I forgot, I'm targeting Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Writing it for WP8 is probably going to be easier. But with the GestureService in the toolkit, it will not take you a ton of time to do it right.